# Computed style in conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting, vba

I would like to change the text color of cells based on their content (name1=blue, name2=red, etc.)
I know I can use conditional formatting but it will need as many rules as possible values for the name column.

is there some super-tricky way I'm not aware of to compute the formatting based on a table witch would contains all possible value/color pairs and so, having only one conditional formatting rule?

```
value color
name1  blue
name2  red
name3  green
...    ...
```

Comment: An alternative that I'll mention is to type name1 in a cell A1, and create a CF rule `=$A$1` so that typing in this cell will dynamically change which cells are formatted. You can apply `Data Validation` to this cell so that the user can use a dropdown to select a name. You could do the same with, say, A2 and A3 so that they can have three different names, and colours, at any one time.

Comment: You might be able to apply the camera tool method that I discuss in [this post](http://yoursumbuddy.com/conditional-formatting-color-scales-based-on-other-cells/). You could have a separate sheet with a scale applied based on the names, conditional format it with a color scale and then use the camera tool to overlay the two ranges.

Comment: @DougGlancy That's an interesting (cool) use of the Camera. I've used it before but never found a sensible/reasonable use for it.

Comment: @AndyG, I've also used it for a dashboard with a bunch of pictures on a sheet, each pointing to a chart or pivot table , etc. on another sheet. It can work quite well.

Comment: @AndyG yes, but if I want to colorize all the possible values for _name_ I still need that many CF rules. no?

Comment: @pnuts I have no problem with VBA so a VBA solution would also be OK

Comment: @Peyre Yes, if you want to colorize all possible values you need VBA to do the formatting. Personally, I don't see the point in having more than 5, or at most 10, colours in a range at any one point, which is why I made my suggestion. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write a script for it I think there is no method to do so.
The closest approach i can think of is using color scale option from conditional formating tab, however as far as i know, it only gives you some default scales with very simple customization.